# Python script to delete lines with repetitive strings

Tags: python

```
This
This line 
This line has
This line has five
This line has five strings
```

I need the script to delete lines 1 through 4 and just print line 5

This looks for exact lines so did not work for me:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
for line in open(infilename, "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: You're looking for exact duplicates instead of partial duplicates.  Use `if not any(seen in line for seen in lines_seen)` instead.

Comment: Also you'll need to remove the newline at the end of `line`, or else the substring won't match.

Comment: @seb, please understand that \```python or \```bash is valid markdown, but \```This is not valid. Bad markdown will sometimes change OP's meaning, as it does here in your Revision 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(infilename) as fin:
    lines = list(map(str.rstrip, fin))
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    while i + 1 < len(lines) and lines[i + 1].startswith(lines[i]):
        i += 1  # duplicate, so skip
    print(lines[i])
    i += 1
```

Feel free to send those surviving lines to an output file, if desired.